# Java program as a Windows Service

Tags: windows, services

I create a Java server, which tools do you recommend to wrap java as a Windows service?

Is it possible to have the service launch in sequence? Say server is start before a Java client can be run?

Comment: Cross-posting is uncalled for.

Comment: erm? What is cross-posting?

Comment: http://kenai.com/projects/winsw works well - is used in Glassfish.  Requires .NET.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a post on [service wrappers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_wrapper).

> - [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/)
> - [Yet Another Java Service Wrapper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yajsw)
> - [JavaService](http://forge.objectweb.org/projects/javaservice)
> - [Apache Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/daemon)
> - [AlwaysUp](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp)